# Is there a way to keep a subset of each group for a pandas groupby object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   id        date  isActive
0   1  2019-01-01         0
1   1  2019-01-02         1
2   1  2019-01-03         1
3   1  2019-01-04         0
4   1  2019-01-05         0
5   2  2019-01-01         0
6   2  2019-01-02         1
7   2  2019-01-03         0
8   2  2019-01-04         1
9   2  2019-01-05         0
```

I want to filter out all inactive (*isActive*=0) rows for each id, unless the most recent rows for that id are inactive. Afterwards, my dataframe should look like this:

```
   id        date  isActive
0   1  2019-01-02         1
1   1  2019-01-03         1
2   1  2019-01-04         0
3   1  2019-01-05         0
4   2  2019-01-02         1
5   2  2019-01-04         1
6   2  2019-01-05         0
```

---

I thought I should try keeping all of the active rows, along with the rows associated with last set of consecutive *isActive* values for each id. To do this, I tried creating a flag that indicates when the *isActive* variable changes, then tried getting the size of each of those groups:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby(['id', df['isActive'].eq(1).cumsum()])['isActive'].transform('size')
```

Then, I tried using `apply` and `tail` to keep each row that satisfied the conditions mentioned above, but I realized I can't just access the *flag* value of the last column:

```
df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: (x['Status'].eq(2)) | (x['Status'].tail(x['flag'])))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think I may be overthinking this problem. Is there some better approach out there?

Comment: Why did you keep `2019-01-04` if it is not the most recent and it is inactive? Was there an error or I missed something?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to `2019-01-04` row where id=1. I want to keep all of the consecutive inactive rows going backwards (if the most recent row for that `id` is inactive). So I would want to keep both `2019-01-05` and `2019-01-04` for id=1, since there aren't any 1s between them. Sorry, I may have not explained my question very well. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Absolutely, that makes sense now.

Comment: As you further explain on keeping only consecutive inactive rows, why do you keep `id=2` `2019-01-05` ?

Comment: Because it is the most recent row for that id. In other words, I want to keep the most recent row for each id regardless. If the final row for that id is inactive, then I want to also keep the rows preceding that row if they are also inactive (and stop including rows until I reach an active row).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if `isActive` is 0 and take the cummulative product from the bottom within group. This will give you `True` for the last streak of 0s (if any). Combine that with all the rows that are `1` and you have your total mask.

```
# Assumes sorted by date within each id
m = (df['isActive'].eq(0)[::-1].groupby(df['id']).cumprod().sort_index()
     | df['isActive'].eq(1))

df[m]
   id        date  isActive
1   1  2019-01-02         1
2   1  2019-01-03         1
3   1  2019-01-04         0
4   1  2019-01-05         0
6   2  2019-01-02         1
8   2  2019-01-04         1
9   2  2019-01-05         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pyjanitor to hook the transform back to the dataframe, shift function to get the value from the next row, and filter out any value equal to -1, since 0-1 will be negative, but 0-0 or 1-1 will not.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyjanitor

(df.groupby_agg(by='id',
                agg=lambda x: x - x.shift(-1),
                agg_column_name='isActive',
                new_column_name='cumu'
                )
 .fillna(0)
 .query('cumu != -1')
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .drop('cumu',axis=1)
)



    id  date    isActive
0   1   2019-01-02  1
1   1   2019-01-03  1
2   1   2019-01-04  0
3   1   2019-01-05  0
4   2   2019-01-02  1
5   2   2019-01-04  1
6   2   2019-01-05  0
```